# To create 2 different graphic models with 1 data set

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
 timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

america region bar chart

world total would be a line chart.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- read.csv ('data.csv')

usa <- data[data$countryName == 'United States', ]

plot(strptime(usa$day,"%Y/%m/%d"),
     usa$confirmed,
     type = "s",
     xlab = "day",
     ylab = "confirmed")
```

You can use another type. Checkout the [doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot).

Comment: america region bar chart

world total would be a line chart.